# How do I differentiate between a string and a negative integer in python

Tags: python, string, while-loop, negative-number

I'm trying to use while loop in my functions but getting problems when I enter data input string. Below is my code.

```
search = input('Enter a string to continue or a negative number to exit:')
while True:
    if int(search) < 0:
        print('its a -ve number')
        break
    elif type(search) == str:
        print('Its a string OK lets run the code and search')
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid input')
```

I'm getting a ValueError on entering string;

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: string value

Comment: Put `if type(search) == str` as your first condition, *before* you try to cast it to an int.

Comment: It works for any data, even if I enter a negative number it gets true.

Comment: You could always put the ```int(search)``` in a try/except block.

Comment: The `input` function always returns a string. The `type(search) == str` check is therefore entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To transform a string into an integer, the common method is to wrap the logic in a try except block which will handle the value error. To improve readability I would suggest creating a method which handles the value error by returning `None` if one occurs.

```
def parse_int(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Now your loop can look like this:

```
while True:
    int_search = parse_int(search)
    if int_search is not None and int(search) < 0:
        print('its a -ve number')
        break
    elif type(search) == str:
        print('Its a string OK lets run the code and search')
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid input')
```

Also note, that the `input` function always returns a string. So checking `type(search) == str` will always returns true. Perhaps you meant to exclude positive numbers?

You also construct the `input` outside the loop, meaning incorrect options will loop forever, telling you that you have entered incorrect data. Place that input request inside the loop.

```
while True:
    search = input('Enter a string to continue or a negative number to exit:')
    int_search = parse_int(search)
    if int_search is not None and int(search) < 0:
        print('its a -ve number')
        break
    elif int_search is not None:
        print('Please enter a valid input')
    else:
        print('Its a string OK lets run the code and search')
```

Yet another option could be to modify the `parse_int` method to return the original string value if you receive a value error. In that case the type would be `search: Union[str, int]`. The logic could look like this (adding type annotations to show how they can be useful):

```
from typing import Union

# Type annotations help document code and can be
# used by static analysis tools like mypy to catch bugs!
def parse_int(value: str) -> Union[str, int]:
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

prompt = 'Enter a string to continue or a negative number to exit:'
while True:
    search = parse_int(input(prompt))
    # isinstance is the preferred way to check types.
    if isinstance(search, int) and search < 0:
        print('its a -ve number')
        break
    elif isinstance(search, str):
        print('Its a string OK lets run the code and search')
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid input')
        # Will bring us back to the start of the loop
        # Causing us to get a fresh input value
        continue
```

Comment: Python 2 would return an `int` instead of `str` if you typed a number.  But nobody should be using Python 2 any more.

Comment: @MarkRansom wait for real haha? I finished migrating all my projects off of 2.7 when 3.7 dropped. I always forget how whacky some of the old quirks were :P

Comment: I realized I still had 2.7 installed even though I never use it, so I fired it up to verify how it works.  It's worse than I thought, it appears to do an `eval` on the input.  If you don't put quotes around your input you won't even get a `str`, you get an exception.

Comment: @MarkRansom That is horrifying.

Comment: Yes it is, I assume that's why they changed it in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The first if condition of the while loop converts the input to `int`. Meaning if the input wasn't an integer, it would return an error as it is not possible to convert a string to an int. So try this:

```
search = input('Enter a string to continue or a negative number to exit:')
while True:
    if search[0] == "-":
        if search[1].isdigit():
            print('its a -ve number')
            break
    elif type(search) == str:
        print('Its a string OK lets run the code and search')
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid input')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, if you don't want to use `try/except` block you can use `regex`.
We can use regex to match a negative number `re.match('^-\d+$', search)`. `isnumeric()` will returns `False` if it finds string characters in the `search`. Keep in mind the while loop is running continuously.

```
import re
search = input('Enter a string to continue or a negative number to exit: ')

while True:
    if re.match('^-\d+$', search):
        print('its a -ve number')
        break
    elif search.isnumeric() is False:
        print('Its a string OK lets run the code and search')
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid input')
```